# unable to locate element in Ruby simple script fail

Tags: ruby, watir

When I run the script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

def adopt_puppy_number(num)
  @browser.button(:value => 'View details', :index => num - 1).click
  @browser.button(:value => 'Adopt Me!').click
end

@browser.goto 'http://puppies.herokuapp.com'
adopt_puppy_number 1
@browser.button(:value => 'Adopt Another Puppy').click
adopt_puppy_number 2
```

I get the exception:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:536:in `assert_element_found': unable to locate element, using {:value=>"View details", :index=>0, :tag_name=>"button"}  (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
  from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:508:in `assert_exists'
  from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:114:in `click'
  from /home/giz/Downloads/RubymineProjects/learn_watir/thirdscript_dry.rb:6:in `adopt_puppy_number'
  from /home/giz/Downloads/RubymineProjects/learn_watir/thirdscript_dry.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
  from -e:1:in `load'
  from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Why? Maybe I should add a wait command, but where exactly and which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML for the View Details button is:

```
<input class="rounded_button" value="View Details" type="submit">
```

Notice that the `value` attribute is "View Details" not "View details". Watir's locators are case-sensitive, which is the element is not found. The `adopt_puppy_number` method should be:

```
def adopt_puppy_number(num)
  @browser.button(:value => 'View Details', :index => num - 1).click
  @browser.button(:value => 'Adopt Me!').click
end
```